# RN Metro Bundler Android bundling complete Twice

Tags: react-native, android-studio, expo, metro-bundler

I am using Expo EAS dev client.

Everytime I start up Metro and try to open the application on android simulator it runs twice causing a lot of problems.

[image]

[image]

It only happen at the first start, if I press "r" to reload or open it again with "a" it loads one time like it suppose to do.

How can I fix this, I don't know where to look to find the cause of this problem.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this? I'm facing the same problem after trying to Deep Link